# Class seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping, query-builder

What I'm trying to do is to get an Post(Post Entity) form where I can select a featured picture from another entity(File Entity).

At the end I would like to display only the files of type "featured Image" but even if I remove my query_builder I've got a exception that says:

> Class "Site\Backend\Adminbundle\Entity\File" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?

Here is my PostType form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
           ->add('title')
           ->add('thumb', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Site\Backend\Adminbundle\Entity\File',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                        //->where('f.state = :state')
                        //->setParameter('state', $prms['state'])
                        ->orderBy('f.dateUpdated', 'DESC');
                }
           ))
}
```

In the other hand I have my two entities:

Here is my File entity

```
<?php

namespace Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\File
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class File {

/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreated", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateCreated;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateUpdated", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateUpdated;

/**
 * @var string $name
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
private $file;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
public $path;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TypeFile", inversedBy="files")
 */
private $type;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Post", mappedBy="thumb")
 */
private $posts;

public function __construct() {
    $this->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());
    $this->setDateUpdated(new \DateTime());
    $this->type = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload() {
    $this->setDateUpdated(new \DateTime());
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
        $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . '.' . $this->file->guessExtension();
    } else {
        //throwException($e);
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload() {
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
    // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
    // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

    unset($this->file);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload() {
    if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}

public function getAbsolutePath() {
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
}

public function getWebPath() {
    return null === $this->path ? null : './' . $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir() {
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir() {
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/' . $this->type;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return File
 */
public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return File
 */
public function setPath($path) {
    $this->path = $path;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get path
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPath() {
    return $this->path;
}

public function __toString() {
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Add type
 *
 * @param Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\TypeFile $type
 * @return File
 */
public function addType(\Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\TypeFile $type) {
    $this->type[] = $type;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove type
 *
 * @param Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\TypeFile $type
 */
public function removeType(\Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\TypeFile $type) {
    $this->type->removeElement($type);
}

/**
 * Get type
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getType() {
    return $this->type;
}

/**
 * Set type
 *
 * @param Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\TypeFile $type
 * @return File
 */
public function setType(\Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\TypeFile $type = null) {
    $this->type = $type;

    return $this;
}

public function getFile() {
    return $this->file;
}

public function setFile($file) {
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Set dateCreated
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
 * @return File
 */
public function setDateCreated($dateCreated) {
    $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateCreated
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateCreated() {
    return $this->dateCreated;
}

/**
 * Set dateUpdated
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateUpdated
 * @return File
 */
public function setDateUpdated($dateUpdated) {
    $this->dateUpdated = $dateUpdated;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateUpdated
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateUpdated() {
    return $this->dateUpdated;
}


/**
 * Add posts
 *
 * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Post $posts
 * @return File
 */
public function addPost(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
{
    $this->posts[] = $posts;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove posts
 *
 * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Post $posts
 */
public function removePost(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
{
    $this->posts->removeElement($posts);
}

/**
 * Get posts
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->posts;
}
}
```

And Here is my Post entity

```
<?php

namespace Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreated", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateUpdated", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateUpdated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="datePublished", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datePublished;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var Author
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="posts")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var Thumb
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\File", inversedBy="posts")
     */
    private $thumb;

    /**
     * @var Comments
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="post")
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @var Categories
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @var Tags
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * Constructeur
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());
        $this->setDateUpdated(new \DateTime());
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->Categories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->title;
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateUpdated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateUpdated
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setDateUpdated($dateUpdated)
    {
        $this->dateUpdated = $dateUpdated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateUpdated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateUpdated()
    {
        return $this->dateUpdated;
    }

    /**
     * Get datePublished
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDatePublished()
    {
        return $this->datePublished;
    }

    /**
     * Set datePublished
     *
     * @param \DateTime $datePublished
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setDatePublished($datePublished)
    {
        $this->datePublished = $datePublished;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set state
     *
     * @param string $state
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setState($state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get state
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\User $author
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setAuthor(\Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\User $author = null)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return \Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Add comments
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment $comments
     * @return Post
     */
    public function addComment(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment $comments)
    {
        $this->comments[] = $comments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove comments
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment $comments
     */
    public function removeComment(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment $comments)
    {
        $this->comments->removeElement($comments);
    }

    /**
     * Get comments
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    /**
     * Add Categories
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $categories
     * @return Post
     */
    public function addCategory(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add Categories
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $categories
     * @return Post
     */
    public function addCategoriesNew(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove Categories
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $categories
     */
    public function removeCategory(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($category);
    }

    /**
     * Remove Categories
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $categories
     */
    public function removeCategoriesNew(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get Categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    /**
     * Get Categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCategoriesNew()
    {
        //return $this->categories;
    }

    /**
     * Add tags
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\tag $tags
     * @return Post
     */
    public function addTag(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
    {
        $this->tags[] = $tags;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add tags
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\tag $tags
     * @return Post
     */
    public function addTagsNew(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
    {
        $this->tags[] = $tags;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tags
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag $tags
     */
    public function removeTag(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
    {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tags);
    }

    /**
     * Remove Tags
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\tag $tags
     */
    public function removeTagsNew(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
    {
        //$this->tags->removeElement($tags);
    }

    /**
     * Get Tags
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    /**
     * Get Tags
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTagsNew()
    {
        //return $this->Tags;
    }

    /**
     * Add Categories
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $categories
     * @return Post
     */
    public function addCategorie(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $categories;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove Categories
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $categories
     */
    public function removeCategorie(\Site\Backend\BlogBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\preUpdate
     */
    public function setUpdateValue(){
        $this->setDateUpdated(new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
     * Set thumb
     *
     * @param \Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\File $thumb
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setThumb(\Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\File $thumb = null)
    {
        $this->thumb = $thumb;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get thumb
     *
     * @return \Site\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\File 
     */
    public function getThumb()
    {
        return $this->thumb;
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance
I hope I was clear, if It is not the case please tell me.

Comment: If i put just `->add('thumb')` instead of the whole statement it works but the fact is that i cant filter the entities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing:

Site\Backend\Admin**b**undle\Entity\File

to

Site\Backend\Admin**B**undle\Entity\File

Comment: Thanks it works ! I'm tired to get blocked bye this kind of issue ... Spending hours looking at the code, I am seeing nothing ^^

Answer (score 0):

An other way to resolve the case :

```
->add('thumb', null, array(
                  'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                      return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                            ->select('f')
                            ->leftJoin('f.type', 't')
                            ->where('t.name = :type')
                            ->setParameter('type', 'Featured Images')
                            ->orderBy('f.dateUpdated', 'DESC');
                  }
               ))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working with multiple connections, you might have forgotten to map your bundle. Make sure it's the case in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
orm:
  entity_managers:
    default:
      mappings:
        AppBundle: ~
        SiteBackendAdminBundle: ~
```

Or if you want to split in several entity managers:

```
orm:
  entity_managers:
    default:
      mappings:
        AppBundle: ~
    admin:
      mappings:
        SiteBackendAdminBundle: ~
```

Documentation [Symfony/Doctrine: Multiple Entity Managers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).